# What happens when one separates a quark-antiquark pair?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quarks, strong-force, confinement

in particular, if the distance is more than about 1 fm?

Comment: Heads up for future, try to make the title about what your question is, rather than 'can you solve this question' or what the topic is. Here 'What happens when a quark-antiquark pair is separated by more than 1fm?' would work here.

Answer (score 2):

At about 1 fm separation the strong force will resist the separation of the quark-antiquark pair any further and create a new quark-antiquark pair between the two. Now you have 2 quark-antiquark pairs using on quark from the newly created pair on each one, shortening the separation once more.

[This](https://www.physicsmasterclasses.org/exercises/hands-on-cern/hoc_v21en/main_frame/pk_z2uppg2.html) is a pretty good link of more or less exactly your question.

Hope that helps, and welcome to SE